# javascript execution order when appended to dom

Tags: javascript

So I found this link that gives good explanation of how scripts are loaded:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

But I'm having some trouble understanding what happens if I do this:

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement("script");   
script.src = "//www.domain.com/script.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);      
</script>

<script>
console.log(myVar);
</script>
```

script.js contains e.g.

```
var myVar = 'foobar';
```

So my question is... since the `script.js` is appended in a separate script tag, does this guarantee that `script.js` will be loaded and executed before the `console.log()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the website you linked:

> **Scripts that are dynamically created and added to the document are async by default**, they don’t block rendering and execute as soon as they download, meaning they could come out in the wrong order.  (emphasis theirs).

This means that execution order is not guaranteed for scripts that have been added to the page via JavaScript (as in your example above).

If you want execution to be deterministic, you'll need to manually disable the `async` property:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");  
script.src = "//www.example.com/script.js";
script.async = false; // overwrite the default
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: hmm okay, so I guess you answered my actual question (so I'll credit that), but overall my goal is to come up w/ a solution to guarantee execution order. Seems that `async` attribute is not currently supported in Opera and didn't start getting supported for IE until 10.  That's kinda a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

In normal script tags are a synchronous and so its blocking:

```
<!-- BAD: blocking external script -->
<script src="//somehost.com/some_script.js"></script>
```

And in case of async without blocking:

```
<!-- GOOD: remote script is loaded asynchronously -->
<script>
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "//somehost.com/some_script.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

OR

```
<script async src="//somehost.com/some_script.js"></script>
```

so for your case its not gurante that script will be loaded before log the var as its one of the options to allow async script load.

[Check this for more info](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/)